# SQL CLR Geography Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

This is probably completely off base - but for some reason I can't declare a variable of SqlGeography type in an SQL CLR function (VB.NET). The following states that SqlGeography is not defined on line 3 - pretty sure I need to import something - but can't find it.

Oh yeah - using SSDT.

Any help appreciated.

```
Public Shared Sub usp_routing_dijkstra(node_1 As SqlGuid, node_2 As SqlGuid)

    Dim StartGeo As SqlGeography

    Using connection As New SqlConnection("context connection=true")
        connection.Open()

        Using command As New SqlCommand("select [geo] from [nodes] where [sys_id] = @id", connection)
            Dim param As New SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
            param.Value = node_1
            command.Parameters.Add(param)
            Dim StartNode As Object
            StartNode = command.ExecuteScalar()
            If StartNode IsNot Nothing Then

            End If
        End Using

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Types ?

Comment: Yes - sorry it took me so long to answer - I've been up to my neck :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Types in your project.  In my case, it is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll.

Then, make sure you have the following Imports at the top of your .vb file:
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

After that, you should be able to declare a variable of type SqlGeography.